# Why one can Control+Option+U to edit a cell on Numbers?

Tags: numbers

It has been noted there are two ways to edit a cell on Numbers, `Option+Enter` seems to do the job.

But still there is `Ctrl+Option+U`, why?

Answer (score 2):

They behave differently. If the cell has a formula inside, <kbd>⌃ Ctrl</kbd>  + <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd>  + <kbd>U</kbd>  erases the formula and makes the user type over it while <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd>  + <kbd>↵ Return</kbd>  allows the user to edit the formula as well.